# Service Worker Cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps

I have the following code which should cache 3 files but when I reload the page and I enter dev tool and network it says that all my files are from service worker. Is my code correct and only those 3 files are cached or all the file are cached?

```
let cache_name = 'v1'
let cache_files = [
 './style/general.css',
 './style/authenticate.css',
'./javascript/app.js'
];


self.addEventListener('install',function(e){
   console.log('[ServiceWorker] installed')
   e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cache_name).then(function(cache){
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching ',cache_files)
     return cache.addAll(cache_files)
  })
 )
});

self.addEventListener('activate',function(e){
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] activated')
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cache_names){
       return Promise.all(cache_names.map(function(this_cache_name){
         if(this_cache_name !== cache_name){
           console.log('[ServiceWorker] removing cached files      from',this_cache_name)
      return caches.delete(this_cache_name)
     }
    }))
   })
 )
})

self.addEventListener('fetch',function(e){
   e.respondWith(
     caches.match(e.request).then(function(response) {
        return response || fetch(e.request);
  })
 );
})
```

And how can I tell which files are cached and which ones are not?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question.

Your code does these things:

- On installation the three files in the array are put in a cache named "v1"
- On future activations the cache is iterated and all items in the cache that don't belong to the cache name ***cache_name*** are removed (that is, if you change the cache_name to "v2" in the future, all "v1" entries are removed automatically)
- On fetch events from the client the cache is checked for the requested file; if the file is found from the cache, the SW returns that, if not, the SW forwards the request to the network

You can inspect the cached files in Chrome Dev tools via the "Application" tab's "Cache Storage" pane on the left side. Check this out and scroll to the bottom: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/local-storage

[image]

Comment: Thnx for showing me this.But there is a reason why my service worker won't cache filse on my android phone even thow it has lates version on chrome?

Comment: @GeorgianStan there shouldn't be any reason for that. Remember that your site has to be served over an HTTPS connection (not plain HTTP).

Comment: In development localhost is a substitute,it works as https it could be a scope problem because in my pc the scope is localhost:3000 but when I connect with my phone I connect to pc ip address which is not localhost and this could be the conflict I will check right now